# Triggering code-behind events with InputBindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Got stuck while adding key-shortcuts to an MVVM app. Searched for a solution but could not find an example where triggering a command was hindered by the DataContext. This leads me to think I'm perhaps trying to do this the wrong way.

See the following example.

**Window XAML**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="Stackoverflow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F" Modifiers="Control"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Interface Action" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window Code-behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do Work
    }
}
```

Trying to link the input binding to the button, what is the best design choice? These are the options I can think of:

1. Setup code-behind to be the Data-Context, create a code-behind property ViewModel and define the path deeper in the XAML tree
2. Write a key-press event in the code-behind and trigger the event from there

Both options seems to be either aesthetically wrong or cause a lot of extra code to be written. What would be the best option from an MVVM point of view?

Comment: It works better if you use "code-behind" instead of "codeback".  Nobody knows what "codeback" means.  Maybe a few, but everybody says "code-behind".